# ¿Se puede generar un link a través de un output en html_options(Select del Smarty)?

Tags: php, smarty

Estoy trabajando con Smarty para un TP de la facu. 
Tengo una tabla de cine que esta relacionada con una de películas, al mostrar los cines realicé un Select con html_options que muestra las películas que están en ese cine. Mi idea es que a su vez cada ítem sea un link que muestre info de ese película en particular, pero por el momento no eh logrado que funcione.

```
{foreach from=$Cines item=cine}
          <tr>
            <td><a href="peliculasPorCine/{$cine['id_cine']}">{$cine['nombre']}</a></td>
            <td>{$cine['capacidad']}</td>
            <td>{$cine['sala']}</td>
            <td>
              <select name=pelicula>
                {foreach from=$Peliculas item=pelicula}
                  {if $cine['id_cine'] == $pelicula['id_cine']}
                      {html_options values={$pelicula['id_pelicula']} output= <a href="">{$pelicula['nombre']</a>}
                  {/if}
                {/foreach}  
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><a href="borrar/{$cine['id_cine']}">BORRAR</a></td>
            <td><a href="editar/{$cine['id_cine']}">EDITAR</a></td>
          </tr>
{/foreach}
```

El error que me aparece con este código es :

Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "file:C:\xampp\htdocs\Web2\templates\home.tpl" on line 29 "{html_options values={$pelicula['id_pelicula']} output= {$pelicula['nombre']}" - Unexpected "<" <-- thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web2\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 29

Por lo cuál yo supongo que no me permite realizar el anchor dentro de la sentencia html_options, pero tampoco se me ocurre como anexarla.

El repo es : https://github.com/LucilaG/Web2